# User-defined contrast on Generalized Estimating Equations

Tags: spss, stata, generalized-estimating-equations, contrasts

I am running a GEE on `SPSS` as well as `Stata` on choice data with the following structure:

Each subject completed 32 trials in 4 blocks, 8 trials per block, on which he/she chose between two options. The four blocks represent two within-subjects factors crossed with each other. Subjects are assigned to one of three between-subjects conditions. Thus, I have a 3 x 2 x 2 mixed design. DV is number of times Option 1 is chosen out of the 8 trials. I used a GEE with a binomial logit link and estimated marginal means for choice percentage by condition.

Everything else is fine, but I am running into a little question that I do not have an answer to and I hope someone can help.

**I need to test the hypothesis that the choice share of Option 1 in a particular condition is different from chance (50%).**

The pair-wise comparisons only allow me to test differences between conditions and not between a condition and a user-defined value. Can anyone help?